# How to package multi folder python apps using pyinstaller

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

Im trying to package an application using pyinstaller on mac. The application has afew folders such as data, which contains json files.

When i try package the application doing `pyinstaller --onefile app.py` as i would on a windows machine and then try to run it i get "file cant be found" error.

What could be causing this? I tried adding the folder with --add-data but doesnt seem to work.

My code is

```
import json
import os
import sys

with open("./data/userdata.json","r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
file.close()
print(data)
```

The json files are in a folder in the main directory called data

/data/userdata.json

Answer (score 0):

the issue is certainly because the resulting folder structure is not being formed as you are expecting.

You have to imagine this way, once you exe gets converted, it launches in a temporary path and unpacks it's data their.

Since you haven't mentioned the exact --add-data command that you are executing, I'll assume you haven't tried the right one.
Include your add-data command in following format.

```
--add-data="data/*;data"
```